# Imagem com texto dinâmico para enviar por e-mail

Tags: php, imagem

Gostaria de saber se é possível em uma pagina inserir uma imagem de um cupom em .jpg no fundo e sobre a imagem do cupom alguns campos como nome, telefone e e-mail para preenchimento.

Após o preenchimento o usuário clica em um botão enviar e a imagem é enviada em anexo para ele pelo mesmo e-mail que ele preencheu mas com texto dos dados que foram preenchidos já salvos na imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que esse recurso é exatamente o que precisa: 
[OCR in PHP: Read Text from Images with Tesseract](https://www.sitepoint.com/ocr-in-php-read-text-from-images-with-tesseract/)